# The comma and dot (,.) are not getting vertical centrally aligned in traditional Chinese

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, localization, chinese-locale

My application is supporting the Traditional Chinese (**zh-Hant-TW**) language, I am facing one issue while converting the date to specific format the comma and dot are not getting aligned on vertically centre of the sentence. For reference please check the google translation screen shot: [image]

My application output:
In english:
[image]

In traditional chinese:
[image]

this comma should be aligned with this red line in the sentence
[image]

The date time format is:

```
switch languageIdentifier {
    case LanguageIdentifierEnglish:
        return "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a"
            case LanguageIndentifierTraditionalChinese:
        return "yyyy年MM月dd日，EEEE，hh:mm a"
}
```

I have to align this comma in date formatting in centre of sentence as per the google transitional

Comment: Did you set the language as traditional Chinese? (language attribute), else the page may be seen as English with some Chinese characters. Else: try a different font (font is responsible to placement of the dots). You may need to use U+3002 (Ideographic full stop)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks for suggestion, I am wondering how can I replace all the dots because there are lot of strings those needs to be taken care, and we have 8-10 types of supported languages.

Comment: Google translator using **zh-TW** as language identifier but XCode is not showing any option with this particular language identifier.